# Converting IP address to locations, need optimizations

Tags: sql, geocoding, amazon-redshift

I have a list of accounts and IP addresses and I am trying to get a summary of locations. However, the computations are too heavy for our servers to handle and I'm wondering if there's a way to alter my code I can get all my results. The account data set is about 150k rows and 2 columns.

```
select city, state, count(*) from(
    select account_id, 256*256*256*one+256*256*two+256*three+four as Converted, city, state from
       (select *, convert(bigint, split_part(ip_address, '.', 1)) as one, convert(int, split_part(ip_address, '.', 2)) as two, 
       convert(int, split_part(ip_address, '.', 3)) as three, convert(int, split_part(ip_address, '.', 4)) as four from AccountsIP)
     inner join 
     (select city, state, ip_from, ip_to from ip_ranges a left join ip_locations b on a.ip_location_id = b.ip_location_id
      where country = 'US') b 
      on (256*256*256*one+256*256*two+256*three+four) between ip_from and ip_to
) 
group by city, state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Python UDF to convert the IP address to bigint and use that in `BETWEEN` condition:

```
create or replace function ip_to_ipnum (ip varchar)
    returns bigint
    stable as $$
    ip_array = ip.split('.')
    return int(ip_array[0])*16777216+int(ip_array[1])*65536+int(ip_array[2])*256+int(ip_array[3])
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Also, the bottleneck might be in your `ip_ranges` and `ip_locations` tables that must be sorted appropriately. If your data is only in US you can remove all other data instead of filtering and sort the table by `(ip_from, ip_to)` so the lookups are more efficient.

Also, since data in `ip_ranges` and `ip_locations` is not much volatile you can create a physical table with the join of these so you don't have to join them every time in the query above.